Selenium pytest not able to link webdriver to my testfiles from conftest.py at class level scope
This is my conftest file
This is my test file defined
Getting attribute error when i ran
Conftest.py
@pytest.fixture(scope= "class")
def setup(request):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://google.com/')
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver

test_sampletest.py
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class TestBzHomePage:
    def test_benzinga_landing(self):
        # self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "email"))).click()
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "email").send_keys("sankalpsaxena@xxx.com")
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "current-password").send_keys("testtest")

bz1 = TestBzHomePage()
bz1.test_benzinga_landing()

Error I got -
ERROR testCases/test_BzRegression_Suit.py - AttributeError: 'TestBzHomePage' object has no attribute 'driver'
Please help to resolve this issues my goal is to define browser launch in setup across all test files once and yeild when session ends by driver,close
